# Eventhandlers in a MultiView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback, multiview

I tend to use MultiViews quite a lot, and I'm seeing a bizarre problem I've never encountered. Only controls on the first Multiview index or outside it will cause their attached eventhandlers to be fired. The MultiView is inside a UserControl.

I can change the MultiView index, but any controls in any index other than `0` will not fire event handlers. Is there any reasonable cause for this or way I could debug it?

My MultiView is declared as

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnPostTopicAlsoWorking" runat="server" Text="Post Topic" CssClass="button" ValidationGroup="post" OnClick="btnPostTopic_Click"/>
<asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="mltMain" ActiveViewIndex="0" OnActiveViewChanged="viw_Changed">
    <asp:View runat="server" ID="viwCategories">
        ...this works
        <asp:Button ID="btnPostTopic" runat="server" Text="Post Topic" CssClass="button" ValidationGroup="post" OnClick="btnPostTopic_Click"/>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server" ID="viwCategorySingle">
        ...this does not work
        <asp:Button ID="btnPostTopicBroken" runat="server" Text="Post Topic" CssClass="button" ValidationGroup="post" OnClick="btnPostTopic_Click"/>
```

Comment: Is it meant that all buttons should use the same eventhandler?

Comment: No, they're actually all different, I've changed them to the same for debugging.

Comment: When debugging, also check what `ActiveViewIndex` your multiview has, to see if it is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

This was a nightmare to track down. The UC is embedded in an Umbraco page, and the UC is added with a macro. If I create a MasterPage and include the macro like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/umbMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cp_content" runat="server">
    <umbraco:Item ID="Item1"  runat="server" field="bodyText" />
</asp:Content>
```

I can create an Umbraco page, insert the macro with the editor and it'll display and be half functional. To get it to work 'as expected', I needed to embed the macro directly in the MasterPage:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cp_content" runat="server">
    <umbraco:Macro ID="Macro1" runat="server" Alias="forumCategoryFrontEnd"/>
</asp:Content>
```